# Titulo de Aplicacion se ve en el TOOLBAR

Tags: java, android

Actualmente tengo el problema de que el nombre de la aplicación

```
 <string name="app_name">Banred</string>
```

---

Me sale en el `Toolbar` del menú principal y la verdad que no quiero que se vea el nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Mi `toolbar` es el siguiente:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
        android:background="@color/white">
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="55dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
           android:layout_gravity = "center"
           android:background="@mipmap/banred"
           />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

El codigo de OnCreate es el siguiente

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

My Styles.xml es el siguiente

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código de tu actividad?

Comment: ya se lo agrege gracias

Comment: ¿Es **realmente el título** o es que esta imagen contiene el logo y el título `@mipmap/banred`?

Comment: Si yo borro desde string.xml el appname ese banred que esta en negrita se desaparece , pero al hacer eso mi aplicacion ya se queda sin titulo el que aparece abajo del icono

Comment: Creo que el nombre de la app **se agrega desde otra parte**, ¿quizá lo incluyas dentro de otro layout, que incuyes desde el layout del main, algún layout llamado por ejemplo `app_bar_main`? Revisa el layout completo que pones en el main, y  mira si estás incluyendo otra cosa en él. En mi app lo tengo así: `<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />` y allí se agrega el nombre de la App en el ToolBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una solución es quitarlo por código.

este código debes ponerlo en tu `onCreate()` en tu activity principal donde creas tu navigation drawer

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Pero es mejor buscar dónde se agrega, en el layout, y quitarlo allí directamente. De ese modo no hay que estar buscando siempre algo para luego quitarlo.

Comment: pues en su activity principal, donde esta su navigation drawer, ahi es donde debe agregarse le código, solo una vez.

Comment: gracias Miguel!

Comment: Entiendo Miguel, pero no me parece lógico tener algo en el layout si no quieres tenerlo. Creo que **debería buscar dónde está el elemento y quitarlo de forma definitiva**, ya que ese código se ejecutará siempre que se abra la Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Busca la actividad en tu manifest y asígnale un string vacío en el parámetro label

<
activity
 android:name=".activitys.PrincipalActivity"
 android:label=""
/>

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estés incluyendo ese texto desde otra parte.

En mi App de hecho, se incluye el nombre en el ToolBar. Y se incluye de la siguiente manera:

### 1. El layout de la Activity tiene esto, en tu caso sería `activity_home.xml`:

Debes revisar si hay algún `include` en ese layout.

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Como se puede ver, incluye un layout llamado `app_bar_main` y es allí donde se coloca un `TextView` con el nombre de la App:

### 2. `app_bar_main.xml`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Si eliminas ese `TextView`, ya no aparecerá el nombre de la App en el ToolBar.

Comment: muchas gracias Cedano!

Comment: Hola si me permites una critica constructiva, en el `app_bar_main.xml` no siempre existirá un TextView al menos no en mi proyecto y supongo que tampoco en el de @BrunoSosaFastTag. De hecho el nombre se asigna de manera dinámica tomándolo de la propiedad `Label` del `Activity` del manifiesto, no necesariamente toma el nombre del app.

Comment: Gracias @GustavoMora, la idea de la respuesta es indicar que la mejor solución es buscar dónde se agrega el nombre de la App (sea desde otro layout, sea desde otra parte) para quitarlo. De ese modo se evita tenerlo ahí para luego quitarlo por código. No obstante, lo que dices: *De hecho el nombre se asigna de manera dinámica tomándolo de la propiedad Label del Activity del manifiesto, no necesariamente toma el nombre del app*, no me consta, al menos yo no veo en ninguna parte del código compartido que sea así.

Comment: Si comparto lo que dices pero la respuesta me parece incompleta por lo que mencionaba, no existe el text view en el xml.

Comment: @GustavoMora puede existir en un include... tampoco el OP ha puesto el xml completo de su activity. Y en el código compartido no se ve por ningún lado que se agregue el `TextView` con el nombre de la App de forma programática.

Comment: Pues justo eso _"Puede existir un include"_ es una suposición que no me consta. Lo que es definitivo y basado en hechos es que la respuesta de @MiguelOsorio es definitiva ya que sin importar el XML es una solución correcta. De nuevo comparto tu pensamiento de que si no usas algo en el app mejor quitarlo. Pero tu respuesta no es definitiva y esta basado en tu proyecto como bien mencionas partiendo del supuesto de que el OP tiene el mismo xml tuyo.